# action listener of the bar button does not get called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

in my ViewController I have a barButton, and I created a listener for it as shown in the code posted below.

at run time, when I click the barButton the log message in the bar button Action method `onBarButtonPressed` doe snot display.

please let me know how to create an action listener for the bar button?

**code**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

 @interface ViewController ()

 @end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a  
 nib.

 [self collectValues];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)onBarButtonPressed:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"CLICKED");
}

- (void) collectValues {
self.textFieldValueToDispatch;
}

@end
```

**image**

[image]

Comment: can you add some related code this

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the code is posted

Comment: @user2121 check the connection of `UIBarButton` in `Sent Events` section

Comment: @AnuragSharma please see the image posted above in my question.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik please see the picture posted above in my quest.

Comment: @user2121 - you are selected the wrong class

Answer (score 0):

Check the sent actions in the connection inspector .  You have triggered a segue on bar button in your screen shot [image]

Comment: please check the attached screen shot above in my question.

Comment: you have triggered a segue on that event??

Comment: you have to programatically use prepareForsegue method and remove the segue from storyboard then your button click will work

Comment: You are right, But both should be working. Segue as well as the action!

Comment: but as far as I know, If I want to use prepareforsegue, I should create a segue from the button to the next scene in the storyboard..right?

Comment: no you have to create segue from one view controller to other then give a identifier to segue now from your view controller fire self.performseguewithidentifier method